How to remove snd-aloop kernelmodule?
I use snd-aloop for capturing audio from my PC. It works well, but I cannot remove the loop module, not even after insertion (after a clean reboot):
$ sudo modprobe 
$ sudo rmmod snd-aloop
rmmod: ERROR: Module snd_aloop is in use

How can I remove snd-aloop?
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS on Intel i3

find out what is using it.  Probably you have a service active you need to stop. (alsa perhaps?)

But it strange: I have do nothing between the two command. Explicitly I have done nothing.

lsmod | grep snd_aloop

will show what module is using it. Check the used_by column and see of you can unload them (or also remove these).
You can also do it like this:
echo -e "snd_aloop\n" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf

This will stop loading it but requires a reboot. After that rmmod will work.
